# Vue.js: Unable to catch an event with a point in name using "v-on"

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I am using Vue.js (2.6) with DataTables.js and trying to catch the [Page change event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page).

The page change event in Datatables is named `page.dt` (like all DataTables events, it has the namespace `dt` after the dot)

If I try to do it according the documentation, it does not work.
I guess, it does not work since Vue uses the dot in the event name to define event modifiers, like for example `click.once`

My question is: **Is there any way to catch such events with a dot in the name using Vue?**

Here is the HTML directive:

```
 <table class="table" id="dataTable" v-on:page.dt="pageChange">
```

Here is my method `pageChange`:

```
  methods: {
            pageChange(e) {
                var info = datatable.page.info();
                alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
           }
  }
```

The following jQuery event handler works perfectly:

```
  $('#dataTable').on('page.dt', function () {
            var info = datatable.page.info();
            alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Vue.js + Datatables.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.css"/>
    </head>

<body class="p-4">
    <div class="container fluid">
        <div id="app">
            <div class="table-responsive-xl">
                <table class="table" id="dataTable" v-on:[`page.dt`]="pageChange">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Id
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Candy
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Height
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Weight
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var datatable = null;

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
   computed: {
        table: function () {
            return datatable;
        }
    },
   methods: {
        pageChange(e) {
            var info = this.table.page.info();
            alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
        }
  }
       
});

datatable = $("#dataTable").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json",
    dataSrc: "pokemon"
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "candy" },
    { data: "height" },
    { data: "weight" }
  ]
});

/* $('#dataTable').on('page.dt', function () {
    var info = datatable.page.info();
    alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
});
 */

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the dynamic argument syntax:

```
v-on:[`page.dt`]="pageChange"
```

or:

```
@[`page.dt`]="pageChange"
```

Note the use of backticks. You can't use other forms of quotes as they aren't allowed in attribute names.

**Update:**

I investigated further using [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fc3qms0/) provided.

The code I provided *does* add a `page.dt` event listener to the `<table>` element. You can see that in the developer tools:

[image: Developer tools screenshot]

So if you want to catch an event with a dot in its name using Vue then the code I suggested is correct.

However...

That is not what is actually required here.

`page.dt` is a namespaced jQuery event. The actual event is called `page`, not `page.dt`. jQuery will internally filter by the namespace when the event fires but the event itself is called `page`. When you use jQuery to add the event `page.dt` you'll see that it adds a `page` event to the DOM:

[image: Developer tools screenshot]

So you might think that we can fix this by using `v-on:page` instead. I certainly did. But alas no.

DataTables calls jQuery's `trigger` method to fire the `page.dt` event. That does two things:

1. It calls all the listeners that have been registered via jQuery. This is how the `alert` gets shown when using the jQuery example.
2. It triggers the native event. Or at least, that's what it claims to do. What it actually does (from looking at the jQuery code) is try to call a method on the element with the same name as the event. For native events that may well work but for a custom `page` event it doesn't do anything.

So the reason Vue cannot detect the event is because no DOM event is ever triggered. It's all internal jQuery magic, not a true DOM event.

However, this does provide us with a Vue-based workaround.

Given jQuery will attempt to call a method called `page` on the element we can provide it with just that:

```
:page.prop="pageChange"
```

I tried that with your Fiddle and it does work.

Comment: I have added a code snippet with your solution and it does not work. :-(

Comment: Yes, it does work!  ``<table class="table" id="dataTable" :page.prop="pageChange">``

Answer (score 0):

Add `ref="dataTable"` to your table, and access via `this.$refs.dataTable` in your method

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable" ref="dataTable" v-on:page.dt="pageChange">
```

```
  methods: {
            pageChange(e) {
                var info = this.$refs.dataTable.page.info();
                alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
           }
  }
```

Another way is use `$event` (i am not sure it works or not cuz dont have access to check)

```
<table class="table" id="dataTable" v-on:page.dt="pageChange($event)">
```

```
  methods: {
            pageChange(event) {
                var info = event.target.page.info();
                alert('Showing page: ' + info.page + ' of ' + info.pages);
           }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah based on [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/438#issuecomment-181144820), it looks like you'd have to manually use `addEventListener` on the DOM ref instead of the `v-on` template syntax

Comment: when you pass event , you are using `v-on:page.dt`

Comment: This does not work either, since you are trying to get it working the same way as I did with ``v-on:page.dt``. And this way does not work with Vue 2.6. See the comment before.